# variables issue in GAS using array

Tags: google-apps-script

I couldn't really find a good title for this question... sorry about that :-)

It should be something like :
**a simple question on something that really bothers me** :

in this (very) basic code I'd like to keep the variable `headers` intact and it doesn't... why and how can get a simple way to keep that value unchanged when I modify the `otherVersion` ?

The sheet is a simple row of cells containing a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j in successive cells.

```
function myFunction() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  var headers = data[0];
  Logger.log(headers);
  var otherVersion = data[0];
  var x = otherVersion.shift();
  Logger.log(x)
  Logger.log(headers);// why has it changed ?
}
```

Logger result :

```
 [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j]
  a
 [b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j]
```

I need a 'normal' and a 'shifted version' of this header, that's why I use 2 different var names. Why this weird interaction ? what's the logic behind this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `data[0]` is an array. Doing `var otherVersion = data[0];` doesn't create a copy instead it works on the same copy. Use the slice() function instead.

```
var otherVersion = data[0].slice(0);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, however something is still unclear to me : when I refer to [this doc](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) it says the splice is used to add/remove part of an array and that a second parameter is required to tell how many item to remove... but here I don't remove anything (wich is a good thing for me in this case :) and you use only 1 parameter. So something must be missing in the mentioned doc... can you explain ? thanks in advance.

Comment: Serge, splice() and slice() are different functions :) See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp for more info on slice(). The function you are referring to is splice() with a 'p'